# Some Readline keyboard shortcuts broken in gnome-terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-terminal

I'm trying out `Fedora 27`, and I've noticed they messed around (in an unwelcome way) with the keyboard shortcut in gnome-terminal. Specifically, `M-f` and `M-b` don't work. I've tried googling but all I've found so far is ancient SO posts with solutions that don't work anymore.

Does anybody know what exactly they futzed with? It'd be really nice to have them back again, terminal navigation without them is extremely tedious.

UPDATE: This behavior can also be found in `Ubuntu 17.10`.